# Drupal Commerce SKU generator

Tags: 7, commerce

I am building a Drupal Commerce site and I had the weirdest request:

Upon creating a new product, the client want's to select the product's category from a select list or something similar. This should result in the first part of the product's SKU, say

"CAT007"

Then he want's to select another attribute for that specific product which produces the second part of the SKU, say

048

So the complete SKU of the product would be CAT007.048 thus resulting in a unique identifier. The reason for this is that he doesn't want to look within huge arrays in order to produce the correct SKU.

My problem is that I can't seem to find a decent solution with which I can give the client access and management over the arrays.

Can anyone come up with something?

EDIT something that came to mind was taxonomy terms that contain a field with their SKU prefix/suffix. The problem that arises from that is how can I pass the tid from the user's selection (javascript) to the php side in order to do a term_load() and get the field's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load()` and `taxonomy_get_tree()` I was able to extract the 2 taxonomies I needed for creating the prefix and suffix of the SKU.

I created tables of key, value pairs that contained the tids and the SKU codes.

By using `json_encode()` I was able to pass those tables into an inline js script I attached to commerce's product form using `$form['#attached']['js']`.

Now by having a JavaScript array mapping tids to SKU parts, it's easy using jQuery to fill in the SKU textfield accordingly. :)